# How to make a user defined object?

Tags: c++, object

I'm trying my first project in c++ by making a budget app, however I can't figure out a way for the user to be able to add an expense.  Is there any better way than going into the code and creating an object anytime we add something new?

Comment: The easiest solution is to have a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) you can use to hold an arbitrary number of expenses objects. When you need a new one , just call `emplace_back` or `push_back`, depending on how you want to create the object. Note that `push_back` does force you to make a throw-away object you can pass as a parameter.

Comment: If you aren't allowed to use `std::vector`, a common (and, IMHO, silly) restriction placed on programming assignments for beginning programmers, you'll have to determine the maximum number of allowable expenses and use a fixed size array or write your own simpler version of `std::vector` that can resize as needed.

Comment: When You say "going into the code and creating an object" do you mean "going into the code and creating another variable to store the expense"? Because you shouldn't be making a new variable for every expense - pretty much, whenever you have more than two of the same object you should be using a  container (like a vector) to store them and not make individual variables for each one.

Comment: @user4581301 `push_back` also has a version that takes rvalue [references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).